# Automatic namespaces import

Tags: visual-studio, import, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Is there a way in Visual Studio (a hotkey) to automatically import a type (or choosing between known namespaces) like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in Eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Keyboard Shortcut to automatically add the needed Using statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148977/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-automatically-add-the-needed-using-statement)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

When the red caret appears at the end of your member, just hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, then use arrows keys to choose the right option:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't automatically add the right 'using' declaration though. Resharper will.

Comment: Your cursor needs to be on the class/interface name you typed for this to work.

Comment: wow, that's totally intuitive and absolutely easy to do with one hand - wtf microsoft?

Comment: didn't have a red caret in vs2015, but this worked for me

Answer (score 80):

Yes, Visual Studio can add the `using` for you. When you type in a class name, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (the first option is 99.99% the right one, so just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>). And you can have it add the `using` at the top of the file for the namespace of that class. I use it all the time.

This is easier than <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> as it's fewer keys and the <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> are closer.

Comment: Yeah, CTRL + . is shorter - Thanks for the tip. Sounds buggy too in VB.NET

Comment: I don't think this exists in express editions. I think I need to stop being cheap.

Comment: Thanks.  There are surprising a lot of wrong answers to this question out there

Comment: Your cursor needs to be on the class/interface name you typed for this to work.

Comment: Ctrl + space doesn't work in VS 2017 Community Edition.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't think Ctrl+Space is mapped to anything.

Comment: Opt + Enter for Mac

Answer (score 6):

Look at [JetBrain's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains) excellent [ReSharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#ReSharper_Ultimate) product. It does this for you.

Comment: I lost my `Alt` + `Enter` shortcut and had to go searching for it. The binding is `ReSharper_AltEnterFeelingLucky`

Comment: cough cough advert