# What is Visual Studio's equivalent of Ctrl + Shift + O shortcut in Android development in Eclipse?

Tags: android, vb.net, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been doing some Android development and found that Ctrl+Shift+O shortcut is quite handy for someone like me who is still getting used to what imports are necessary for different objects on the screen. I have also been doing vb.net development in Visual Studio 2008 and by mistake tried that shortcut however it tried opening a form or something similar. So my question is: is there a shortcut that lets us import all missing references or remove the unnecessary ones in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To Remove Unnecessary Import Directives

I can confirm that in Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 there is a context menu option for the code-editor to remove, sort or remove and sort using directives in either Visual Basic.NET or C#. I've actually never used Visual Studio 2008 but a quick search reveals that it is possible in 2008 too ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514114%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

[image: ..]

In order to hook this functionality up to a hotkey all you need to do is:

1. Go to Tools > Options
2. Expand the root node annotated 'Enviroment' and then click the node annotated 'Keyboard'
3. Search for *Edit.RemoveAndSort* and assign your hotkey of choice.

### To Add Unknown Import Directives

I use this plugin called [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which presents me with an interface like this when I reference a class that does not have an appropriate import directive:

[image]

If you don't want to use ReSharper (it's pretty expensive) then Visual Studio has a slightly less productive but just as effective interface. You should see the class reference underlined in red and if you hover your mouse to the red line you should see a little dialog displaying the option to add a reference to the namespace. You can also press `CTRL + .` to show the dialog quickly.

Comment: exactly what i needed. Thanks a bunch and +1 for effort

Answer (score 1):

From this link:

[Automatic namespaces import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186895/automatic-namespaces-import)

Looks like `Shift + ALT + F10` will do the trick.

Comment: That's View.ShortSmartTag, which is quite dope, to be fair, but doesn't fix all your usings in one fell swoop, which Ctrl+Shift+O does for Java's imports in Eclipse.