# How to have return type from async

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using below code to have return type from async, but it throwing an error

```
async Task<double> getDuration(string fileFullPath)
{    
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localRoot = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder mp3 = await localRoot.GetFolderAsync(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileFullPath));
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await mp3.GetFileAsync(Path.GetFileName(fileFullPath));
    Windows.Storage.FileProperties.MusicProperties music = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
    return music.Duration.TotalSeconds;
}
```

The error:

> The type or namespace name 'Task' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I have the return value from async?

Comment: Did you have namespace 

`using System.Threading.Tasks;` on top..?


 





                                           If you don't add this namespace.. Let me know is it working or not..

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been searching for this namespace since hour :)

Comment: Check the Link for more about adding nameSpaces in visual studio

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148977/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-automatically-add-the-needed-using-statement ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The type or namespace name 'Task' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I think you haven't added the namespace

[System.Threading.Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> How can i have the return value from async?

**Sample Code**

```
public async Task<int> ExampleMethodAsync()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    int exampleInt = (await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com")).Length;
    ResultsTextBox.Text += "Preparing to finish ExampleMethodAsync.\n";
    // After the following return statement, any method that's awaiting
    // ExampleMethodAsync (in this case, StartButton_Click) can get the 
    // integer result.
    return exampleInt;
}
```