# Process.Start not being recognised

Tags: c#, .net

Ok, so when I am typing in `Process.Start("Chrome.exe")` into my code, it doesn't light up, and there are no suggestions for what I might want to do, as it normally does in Visual Studio. I'm not sure why this is, does anyone know?

The error message that I receive under `Process` is:

> The Name "Process" does not exist in the current context

Comment: what type of app are you writing?

Comment: i.e. what kind of project did you create?

Comment: @DanielA.White  Console Application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `System.Diagnostics` namespace

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

or use full name:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process...
```

Comment: An easy way to do this is type "Process" then press Ctrl + . (Ctrl + period) and choose to either add the using or to use the full name. (See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148977/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-automatically-add-the-needed-using-statement)