# Implementing abstract classes while adding the necessary using directives

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Lets assume we have the following abstract base class that declares a parameterized method, whereas the parameter lives in another namespace:

```
using Example.SubNamespace;    
namespace Example
{
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public abstract void Method(Parameter param);
    }
}
```

Following a simple class that acts as our parameter (note the different namespace):

```
namespace Example.SubNamespace
{
    public class Parameter
    {
    }
}
```

When implementing a sub class, visual studio offers the option "Implement Abstract Class" when right-clicking the derived class. I've done that in the following example:

```
namespace Example
{
    public class SubClass : BaseClass
    {
        public override void Method(SubNamespace.Parameter param)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Call me petty but sometimes it seems very annoying to me having the fully qualified namespaces within the methods signature.

Is there any possibility to implement an abstract class while automatically inserting the correct using directives? Changing these things manually seems like an unnecessary effort to me.

Comment: Resharper does this out of the box if I recall correctly (and apart from that is a superb VS addon).

Comment: Indeed, seems to be a nice extension. Might worth a try.

Comment: definitely do, everyone I know who tried it now consider it an integral part of the IDE :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do this. Consider placing your `SubClass` and `BaseClass` in the same `namespace`. I don't think this is a big deal.

You can also use intellisense to add namespaces:

[Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to automatically add the needed 'using' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148977/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-automatically-add-the-needed-using-statement)