# Generate "using" directive from fully-qualified class name without having to go to the top of the code file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a shortcut for adding a `using` directive without having to leave the point where I'm working in the code to scroll up to the top of the file?

For instance, if I don't have `using System.IO;` and I add `string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path1, path2);` to a method where I'm working, I'd like to be able to right-click or something to get the option to add `using System.IO;` at the top and remove it from the beginning of `System.IO.Path.Combine`.

I'm know third-party tools like Re-Sharper can enable this, but I thought this would be a simple feature that would be present by VS 2017.

Comment: @OrGroman -- Thank you, that's awesome!

Comment: @OrGroman -- Frustrating....it worked once, and now I can't get it to work again.  Don't know what I'm doing differently.

Comment: Right-clicking on it always works when you have an IntelliSense error, as does the keyboard shortcut. If it isn't working, then there probably isn't an error. Is it underlined in squiggles?

Comment: @CodyGray -- Can you please re-open?  I was almost done writing up my own answer as I believe this is a different question now.  If you don't agree, you can re-close, certainly.

Comment: In short, this ctrl + . trick doesn't work unless you remove the namespace component from the beginning of the class name.  This only works if you have code which already only uses the un-qualified class name (maybe you copy/pasted, or a snippet).  I struggled to figure out for a while why I couldn't get it to work, until I realized I had to delete the ns first from the beginning of the class name.

Comment: @CodyGray -- See updated question.

Comment: Not really sure it's an entirely different question, just a subtle variation, but if you already have a good answer, you might as well post it in the answer box, rather than in the question. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray  I can't post it in the answer box because you closed the question. That immediately grayed out the button. Anyway the key difference here is that the keyboard shortcut simply does nothing at all if you have the fully qualified namespace which confused me for a while (as you can see by my comment where I said it only worked once). I'd like to help others avoid this confusion.

Comment: Err, yeah, I reopened it just before posting that comment.

Comment: @CodyGray -- thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I thought this was an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148977/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-automatically-add-the-needed-using-statemen), it's actually different.  The linked question assumes you *have not already provided the fully-qualified class name*.  For instance, if you happen to have `string fullPath = Path.Combine(path1, path2);` instead of `string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path1, path2);` and without the using directive `using System.IO;` at the top of the file -- maybe you inserted a code snippet or copy/pasted from somewhere else -- you can place your cursor near the class (`Path`) and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to [activate the smart tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3shw4wa2(v=vs.90).aspx).

This is different from my question because I *have* already provided the fully-qualified class name `System.IO.Path` (because maybe I couldn't have found `Path` without it).  I'd like it to recognize that there's a namespace component that can be converted into a `using` directive and remove the namespace component from the beginning of `Path`.  If you do already have the namespace component before the class name, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> shortcut, **does not work**, and there is no explanation provided.  The work-around is to type out the fully-qualified class name, then *delete the namespace component*, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.  This allows you to make use of the intellisense for getting the class name you're looking for from whatever namespace it resides in, and then use the smart tag to add the `using` directive.